# What keyboard layout should I use?

Tags: 14.04, server, keyboard, keyboard-layout, logitech

I already tried `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` without success. I have the Hungarian version of Logitech K360, but I don't have special characters, like `öüóőúéáű`. Everything else seems to be fine. Any tips about which layout to choose?

I tried Logitech based with standard Hungarian, Generic 101 key layout and many others. Nothing seems to work. What is interesting, that a year ago I was able to select the proper layout without any trouble an as far as I know the OS image file did not change since then.

By some of the characters I got nothing in the console, by others, I got something like `(arg: 1)`.

edit:

I might have found something related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1565236

The actual device is [Odroid XU4](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:odroid-xu4) (ARMv7) and I am using the [manufacturer's Ubuntu server image](http://odroid.in/ubuntu_14.04lts/).

The keyboard is a Logitech K360 with Hungarian keys. I counted, it has 101 keys + 6 music control keys on the top.
[image: k360hun]

edit2:

Here is what I have tried so far:

`dpkg-reconfigure locales` # nothing happened

`dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`setupcon`

`reboot`

I still don't have a Hungarian keyboard layout, no matter how I try. The `úőéűáé` characters do similar things when I use the arrows. In nano some of the characters work, but I got a dot like character instead of `ű`. Sorry for the long post I decided to include images to be more thorough. And yes we are still talking about an Ubuntu server without GUI. I used the same image last time in february and it worked properly with the same keyboard. I guess they changed something in the image, since I don't have SD card mounting errors by boot, but I have this keyboard issue. Any clues about how to investigate this further?

Comment: What changed since a few months ago?

Comment: @OwenHines I had a lot of power outages and the system did not want to boot (it's on an SD card), so I rewrote the OS from an image file.

Comment: Oh, so you completely re-installed 14.04 and after the install, it stopped working?

Comment: @OwenHines I did not save the original one, I have only a base image file, which has US English keyboard layout http://odroid.in/ubuntu_14.04lts/ and some instructions I wrote about a year ago. Next time I'll save it after I am done with configuration... :S

Comment: @OwenHines We are talking about an http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143452239825 , so it has ARMv7. My link contains the OS image made by the manufacturer.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misinterpreted what you were saying.

Comment: It does not really matter btw. I am accessing it with ssh now, so I can do everything without touching its keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a £ above the 3, a € symbol on the 4, a # and a ~ to the left of the carriage return (enter) button and a \ | key to the left of the Z then it's a UK keyboard.

If you have a # above the 3, a \ next to return then it's likely a US layout. If it's not one of those, it's probably a Swiss keyboard, since Logitech is a Swiss company.

If none of these options work, then upload a picture of it.

Edit: From the picture, yes. That is an Hungarian keyboard. If there are more versions of the Hungaria layout, it's probably the simpler one. 
If you go to System Settings > Keyboard > Text Entry > The keyboard button at the list, you can see how the keyboard is supposed to look.

Comment: I added a picture.

Comment: @inf3rno i edited the answer. Hope that helpls.

Comment: It is an Ubuntu server, I have console only. I already tried the simple ones with `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but it did not work. I am not sure why.

Comment: @inf3rno https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ#Hungary if you look at the images, it's exactly like your keyboard.

Comment: Yes it is. I already knew that. :-) I'll update my question with further photos. :D